# How do I send logs to mysql using fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I have made one django application and I want to use fluentd to log my API call's, basically I want to send log from django to my SQL database using fluentd.

Here is my code below:

```
<match **>
  @type mysql_bulk
  host 127.0.0.1
  database masking_tool_db
  username root
  password 
  column_names request, response
  table fluentd_logs
  flush_interval 10s
</match>
```

But I'm not able to install the plugin.

Here is the error I got:

```
ERROR:  Error installing fluent-plugin-mysql:
        The last version of mysql2 (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 0.5.3. Try installing it with `gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3` and then running the current command again
        mysql2 requires Ruby version >= 2.2, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.
```

Comment: Please add more details and show what you have tried

Comment: <match **>
  @type mysql_bulk
  host 127.0.0.1
  database masking_tool_db
  username root
  password 
  column_names request, response
  table fluentd_logs
  flush_interval 10s
</match>
i want log to mysql db but didn't able to install mysql_bulk plugin only 
OS-windows

Comment: you can add your code to the question by clicking the edit button below the post, and also dont forget to format the code wth code fences

Comment: done @I_love_vegetables you can check and let me know.

Comment: awesome, i have retracted my downvote :D